# Power BI / DAX - Measure to filter a table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table in Power BI with several columns. Two of the columns (called 'month' and 'year') contain 0's and 1's, and I'd like to use them for a slicer with two options/actions:

1. filter for 1's in column 'month'
2. filter for 1's in column 'year'

So all visuals on my page would be affected by that - showing only particular rows from the table.

I created a disconnected table for the slicer.
Now I need a measure, and I don't know how to correctly create it.

I created this:

MyMeasure =

VAR SelectedOption = SELECTEDVALUE('SlicerOptions'[Options])

RETURN

```
SWITCH(

    SelectedOption,

    "show_month", FILTER('MyTable', [month] = 1),

    "show_year", FILTER('MyTable', [year] = 1),

    'MyTable'

)
```

I receive this error for the measure:
"The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value."

I kind of understand what the problem is...
But how do I achieve what I need?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I would create a parameter that allows you to select one of the columns, and then just use that parameter value in your visual/measure. Because (1) you can specify a list of columns in a parameter, (2) you can then use that selection in your visual/measure.

Comment: @Pieter Yes, but I don't really need to switch columns in my visuals, rather, I need to _filter_ by different columns. And a parameter won't help me for that, am I right?
The columns containing 0's and 1's are only helper columns that probably don't have to be used at all. What I need is a slicer with kind of overlapping values. I came across a number of solutions that say: create a disconnected table for the slicer, and then create a measure to filter the table. But how do I create this measure?